# Ruby on Rails: How to check if the Model Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to know how to check if the model already exists in the project or not?

When user tries to create a model programatically using the same model name, need to check if it already exists or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`defined? ModelName` will return "constant" if model defined.

Comment: `defined?` doesn't seem to return consistent results. Please check the code below:

`
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.2.1 :001 > defined?(User)
 => "constant" 
2.2.1 :002 > defined?(AuthenticationToken)
 => nil 
2.2.1 :003 > AuthenticationToken
 => AuthenticationToken (call 'AuthenticationToken.connection' to establish a connection) 
2.2.1 :004 > defined?(AuthenticationToken)
 => "constant" 
2.2.1 :005 > 
`

Comment: Agree^ it seems that some constants are only loaded after referenced?

Comment: Here's a link to more info on the `defined?` operator: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UG

Answer (score 3):

Since `defined?` is problematic (see @Jiggneshh Gohel's comment), perhaps you can check the filenames in the `models` dir.

```
files = Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/*.rb']
models = files.map{ |m| File.basename(m, '.rb').camelize }

models.include? "User" => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use [exists](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class)

Return false if there is no column in the model.